# Simple send/receive interface to a background Java service application

Tags: java, linux, shell, user-interface, service

I have a headless Java application that perpetually runs in the background, like a service/daemon I suppose. It's running on Linux and collects data, storing it in a database, on continuous loop.

It's started and stopped with an `init.d` script. Which starts the jar running in the background upon system start, and stops it by killing the particular java process upon system shut-down. Plus I can access this script to manually start/stop, like this:

```
sudo service my-java-app stop
```

Despite being primitive, this has sufficed. But now I'm hoping to use a more elegant interface. This will allow me to send commands (i.e. change data acquisition frequency and friendly termination), and request data (i.e. health check and statistics).

I've never done this before and I'm looking for some guidance on where to start. The app runs in the background on a headless Linux, so a GUI isn't suitable. I've thought of running a http server and listening for POST and GET, but that's not simple to implement or use in bash. I've thought there may be a virtual COM port or something that I could create?? Or even a text file that I write to and the app reads on interval?

I image the end goal would be a method to execute commands in bash and have the java application listening/attached to this somehow.

Comment: What about netcat? You cand send anything and wrapped in a simple script it would be pretty easy

Comment: I think it depends on how you want to make the requests: using HTTP GET/POST seems the right thing if you want access from other computer/device, just using the browser. You could access from command line using `curl`. But if you don't want remote access maybe this is overkill

Comment: @rpax netcat is a Linux program right? Are you suggesting I wrap this with a ProcessBuilder or something similar? I'm assuming I would then run netcat commands in bash to establish communications.

Comment: @PabloLozano I think HTTP GET/POST would be very handy for remote. I've found a simple server called [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), and an ever simpler one caller [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd), so it may not be overkill considering how easy it is to get a server running. I think this would be very versatile.

Comment: @Darian No, I mean opening a simple socket, and doing something like :
echo "some command to be parsed" | nc localhost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done this once using sockets in the Java code. The Java application was run either as client or daemon. The `main()` entry point checked whether the socket is open to know if the daemon is running already. You can have CLI parameters to say if you want to launch the daemon or send commands.

- on daemon launch, you open a socket on a specific port
- on another launch, you check if a socket is open on that specific port, and send messages to it if it is.

Note: this implies to choose a fixed port, which I didn't like by the way.

Comment: This could be a good solution, but I have a couple beginner questions if you have time: is 'sockets' exclusive to Java? Can another external application talk with this? What protocol or format is the data transferred in? I'm imagining a Java console client which is neat, but it would be even better if it's accessible to bash scripting or other applications.

Comment: @Darian Sockets are not specific to Java, it is a way of doing IPC. If your Java daemon listens to remote commands through a socket, you can send commands from any interface I think. I'm not totally knowledgeable about this to be honest, but you can probably find many things on the internet about sockets.

Comment: @Darian By the way, with the way I did it in my old program, I actually sent commands via the command line. Java does not need a UI ;)

Comment: I've been reading up on IPC which I wasn't familiar with (for anyone else not familiar, 'IPC' is [Interprocess Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)). Looks like it'll do what I require. Thanks for your help. I also like other suggestions like HTTP for future, because I think this will be easier to implement for a remote webpage/JavaScript based interface.